# RegEx help for URL redirection?

Tags: regex, url, web, url-rewriting

I need help creating a regular expression for redirecting my old URL's to new ones. I just switched platforms (to WordPress btw :) and the links are constructed differently. Can anyone see the regex I can use?

```
Events -    
OLD: /cms/events/view/12-03-19/human_rights_framework_for_activists.aspx
NEW: /events/view/human-rights-framework-for-activists/

OLD: /cms/events/view/12-03-26/media_skills_for_activists.aspx  
NEW: /events/view/media-skills-for-activists/

OLD: /cms/events/view/12-03-20/environmental_justice_toronto.aspx
NEW: /events/view/environmental-justice-toronto/

OLD: /cms/events/view/12-04-11/report_back_from_the_un_session_of_the_56th_commission_on_the_status_of_women.aspx
NEW: /events/view/report-back-from-the-un-session-of-the-56th-commission-on-the-status-of-women/

OLD: /cms/events/view/12-03-16/create_your_annual_fundraising_plan_from_scratch.aspx
NEW: /events/view/create-your-annual-fundraising-plan-from-scratch-2-2012-03-16/

News -
OLD: /cms/news/view/11-10-11/culture_of_peace_-press_release.aspx
NEW: /culture-of-peace-press-release/

Catch all -
OLD: /cms/events/view/*
NEW: /events

OLD: /cms/*
NEW: /
```

Comment: why do you want to use reqex? Why not mode_rewrite (.htaccess) file?

Comment: @user160820: And what do you think goes in the .htaccess file? ;-)

Comment: something like  RewriteRule OLD_LINK NEW_LINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use simply `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule old_link new_link
RewriteRule old_link new_link
RewriteRule old_link new_link
```

Comment: only thing is that it is WordPress MU, so I would be polluting the redirects with everyone else's. I am using a redirect WP plugin which I can use regex for each site